# Code not displaying PHP

Tags: php

So I am writing out all my code and it is all the way It should be, but for some reason it doesn't seem to want to output anything on the screen like it should...

Can someone please help me out? 
Thanks

code:

```
$points_disp = $user_data['points'];
$oneFDigit = substr($points_disp, 0, 1);
$oneSDigit = substr($points_disp, 1, 1);
$oneRange = range(1000, 9999);

$tenFDigit = substr($points_disp, 0, 2);
$tenSDigit = substr($points_disp, 2, 1);
$tenRange = range(9999, 99999);

$hunFDigit = substr($points_disp, 0, 3);
$hunSDigit = substr($points_disp, 3, 1);
$hunRange = range(99999, 999999);

$oneMillionFD = substr($points_disp, 0, 1);
$oneMillionSD = substr($points_disp, 1, 1);
$oneMillionRange = range(999999, 9999999);

if ($points_disp < 1000){
    echo $points_disp;
} else if (in_array($points_disp, $oneRange)){
    echo $oneFDigit . "." . $oneSDigit . "k";
} else if (in_array($points_disp, $tenRange)){
    echo $tenFDigit . "." . $tenSDigit . "k";
} else if (in_array($points_disp, $hunRange)){
    echo $hunFDigit . "." . $hunSDigit . "k";
} else if (in_array($points_disp, $oneMillionRange)){
    echo $oneMillionFD . "." . $oneMillionSD . "m";
}
```

Comment: check your error log for errors, maybe there is an Fatal error: Allowed memory size

Comment: There are no errors, i have turned on error reporting and nothing is showing

Comment: put a simple  else { echo 'Nada'; } maybe no condition is met...

Comment: I'm assuming your code begins with `<?php`, is that correct?

Comment: add at last `else{
    echo "no output found";
}` if none of your condition is true !!

Comment: Yes, it does begin with <?php and end with ?>

Comment: Nada is not displaying

Comment: Well, and want is the content of $points_disp ?

Comment: @Saty already tried, not working, nothing is outputting

Comment: For some reason when i get rid of the 4th code block ($oneMillionSD = e.t.c.) it all starts to work again.. :/

Comment: Try to create a new page called "info.php" and add just `<?php phpinfo();` to it. See if PHP Info is shown.

Comment: @AlanMachado It is shown as it should

Comment: This is weird... Try to manually set to show error outputs in your code, something is not right... the 4th block doesn't seem to have anything wrong, unless this `$oneMillionFD = substr($points_disp, 0, 1);
$oneMillionSD = substr($points_disp, 1, 1);` is returning function exceptions, but the errors are failing to be thrown.

Comment: @AlanMachado exactly... I have tried everything :/ I'm trying it on a new form to see if it works

Comment: This is all of your code? Or there is more?

Comment: @AlanMachado there is more, but I'm not going to show it because it is irrelevant. I've just got a 500 Internal Server Error on my screen though, so that might be part of the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this, just dumped your range() because I had a memory problem. I think range is the wrong function to use here, because you'll get some huge arrays and you just want to know if the number is between this values.

BEWARE: the new range array needs minValue and maxValue in this order!

```
$user_data['points'] = 9999;

$points_disp = $user_data['points'];
$oneFDigit = substr( $points_disp, 0, 1 );
$oneSDigit = substr( $points_disp, 1, 1 );
$oneRange = array( 1000, 9999 );

$tenFDigit = substr( $points_disp, 0, 2 );
$tenSDigit = substr( $points_disp, 2, 1 );
$tenRange = array( 9999, 99999 );
//
$hunFDigit = substr( $points_disp, 0, 3 );
$hunSDigit = substr( $points_disp, 3, 1 );
$hunRange = array( 99999, 999999 );
//
$oneMillionFD = substr( $points_disp, 0, 1 );
$oneMillionSD = substr( $points_disp, 1, 1 );
$oneMillionRange = array( 999999, 9999999 );


if ( $points_disp < 1000 ) {
    echo $points_disp;
} else if ( checkInRange( $points_disp, $oneRange ) ) {
    echo $oneFDigit . "." . $oneSDigit . "k";
} else if ( checkInRange( $points_disp, $tenRange ) ) {
    echo $tenFDigit . "." . $tenSDigit . "k";
} else if ( checkInRange( $points_disp, $hunRange ) ) {
    echo $hunFDigit . "." . $hunSDigit . "k";
} else if ( checkInRange( $points_disp, $oneMillionRange ) ) {
    echo $oneMillionFD . "." . $oneMillionSD . "m";
} else {
    echo "nothing found";
}

function checkInRange( $needle, $range ) {
    $min = $range[0];
    $max = $range[1];

    return ( $needle >= $min && $needle <= $max ) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: if you try, don't forget to remove the $user_data['points'] = 9999; this was just for my test

Comment: yes! this worked! thankyou! may I ask? how did this fix it by adding the function?

Comment: well I cannot exactly say what was your problem, but as i tried it, i had a memory issue, because range returns an array with each value between the numbers. so it's better to really check the range and not make new arrays. You said you got an 500 error, if you look in your error_log, there must be the reason. I really think it was a memory error

Answer (score 5):

If the condition is always false, use this:

```
...
} else {
    echo "some value";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems a bit overkill for what you are trying to actually achieve.

```
$points = (string) 99999;

if($points < 1000) {
    echo $points;
}
elseif($points < 9999) {
    echo sprintf('%s.%sk', $points[0], $points[1]);
}
elseif($points < 99999) {
    echo sprintf('%s.%sk', $points[0], $points[1]);
}
elseif($points < 999999) {
    echo sprintf('%s.%sk', $points[0], $points[1]);
}
elseif($points < 9999999) {
    echo sprintf('%s.%sm', $points[0], $points[1]);
}
```

Result: 9.9k

Comment: trust me, you should've seen what I had before haha

Comment: If it is purely down to displaying a points value with a prefix then you can really cut this code down to 1/2 lines